# Returning to a specific slide from another screen

Tags: ionic-framework, slide

I've got a standard slide box setup :

```
<ion-slide-box >

 <ion-slide >
   < some text and a button with ng-click="go('/a-new-html-page')"> 
 </ion-slide >

 <ion-slide >
   < some more text and another button with ng-click="go('/another-new-html-page')> 
 </ion-slide >

</ion-slide-box >
```

When I use my app, I slide to the second box and click the button to be sent to another-new-html-page. This is an options page with a list of check box options.The things I tick here will be shown back in list on the second the second slide box on my starting page - so  I tick one or more options and click the back button...

.. and that where I get stuck. I have returned to back to the main screen of my app but at the FIRST slide box. You have to slide along to the second box to see those changes which of course is not very user friendly.

Is there a way to return back to the FIRST slide box if i hit back from the "a-new-html-page" and the SECOND slide box if I hit back from the "another-new-html-page"

I'm very new to Ionic and probably making all kinds of "school boy" errors so any help would be greatly appreciated!